# Files moved out from Dropbox folder getting physically copied to destination on same logical drive

Tags: windows, ntfs, dropbox

#### Scenario:

Moving files from `...Dropbox/Camera Uploads` folder do a location outside Dropbox folder hierarchy, but still on the same drive.

Under usual circumstances, the move operation does not take long, as only updates do the allocation tables are needed.

However, by observing the *Copy Operation Dialog* plus the time the operation is taking to perform, I inferred files under Dropbox folder are being physically copied to the destination and then erased on the origin, the same way it has to be done when the destination is on another logical drive.

So as to confirm my suspicion, I tried moving files within Dropbox folder hierarchy and the move occurred as fast as expected — by just performing changes to the allocation tables.

#### How I worked around the problem:

I did the move operation and waited for it to conclude, despite it took longer to happen.

#### My questions:

1. Main question: How to proceed so as to  transform the Dropbox folder in an ordinary windows folder, that is, without special treatment regarding copy, move or whatever operation?
2. What could be the reason(s) it was chosen (if it was intentionally configured this way) for Dropbox folder to work this way?
3. How to configure an ordinary folder so that it presents the same properties regarding file move operations?

#### Environment info:

- OS: Windows 10
- File system: NTFS
- Hard drive: Removable USB drive

Comment: I am seeing this behavior for files being moved into Dropbox as well.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer to question 1

As a solution to the main question, renaming the Dropbox folder to something else results in files under Dropbox folder being treated ordinarily regarding file move operations, and thus solving the main problem.